# Isoartinian and isosimple modules

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

I'm reading [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869316000612) by A. Facchini and Z. Nazemian, in wich they discuss modules with chain conditions up to isomorphism. A couple of the main concepts are the following:

**Definition**
We say that an $R$-module $M$ is *isoartinian* if for every descending chain $M\geq M_{1}\geq M_{2}\geq\cdots$ of submodules of $M$, there exists an index $n\geq 1$ such that $M_{n}$ is isomorphic to $M_{i}$, for every $i\geq n$

**Definition**
We say that an $R$-module $M$ is *isosimple* if it is non zero and every non zero submodule of $M$, is isomorphic to $M$.

In sake of my question it will be necessary to know the following facts:

**Fact 1** Every submodule $N$ of an isoartinian $R$-module $M$ is itself isoartinian.

**Fact 2** Every isoartinian $R$-module $M$ contains an isosimple submodule $L$.

I'm trying to write down (with full details) the proof of Theorem 2.9, which establishes the following:

**Theorem** Any isoartinian $R$-module $M$ contains an essential submodule that is a direct sum of isosimple modules.

**Proof** Let $S$ denote the  set of all families of *independent* isosimple submodules of $M$. By Zorn's Lemma, $S$ has a maximal member $W=\{V_{\lambda}\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$. Since every non-zero submodule of $M$ contains an isosimple module, from the maximality of $W$, it follows that $V=\oplus_{\lambda\in\Lambda}V_{\lambda}$ is essential on $M$.

**Question** Can anybody help me with an idea of what do they mean with the word *independent* in the preceding proof? It is quite evident that the *independence* is key to the aplication of Zorn's Lemma, which is where I'm stuck. Everything else in the proof is easy, but the autors don't mention what they mean by *independent* isosimple submodules.

**Attempt** I have tried using non-isomorphic isosimple submodules but it failed.

Any help will be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Assume that we have the following definition: a set of submodules is *independent* if the submodule they generate is naturally isomorphic to their direct sum. Then it is consistent with the proof. So it is likely be the right definition